# Как нарисовать ёлку используя только символы “_” и “*”?

Tags: javascript

Начал изучать javascript. Застрял на задаче.

> Нарисовать елку с символами "_" и "*". Вывести в консоль браузера. И в каждом втором уровне елки должна быть игрушка в виде "o", которая расположена в случайной позиции уровня.

Мой код сейчас такой. Застряла на игрушке.

```js
function stars(n) {
    for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        var str ="_";
        if(i%2 !== 0){
            
        }
        for (var k = 1; k <= (2*i+1); k++) {
                str = str + '*';
        }
        for (var j = 1; j < n-i; j++) {
            str = " "+str;     
        }
        console.log(str+"_");
    }
}
stars(4);
```

Answer (score 4):

```js
function stars(n) {
  for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    var ballIndex = -1;
    var str = "_";
    if (i % 2 !== 0) {
      ballIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * (2 * i + 1)) + 1;
    }
    for (var k = 1; k <= (2 * i + 1); k++) {
      str = str + ((ballIndex == k)? 'o' : '*');
    }
    for (var j = 1; j < n - i; j++) {
      str = " " + str;
    }
    console.log(str + "_");
  }
}
stars(6);
```