# Python 3, командная строка, рисуем елку

Tags: python

[image: Задание]

Как лучше выполнить эту задачу? вот что у меня получилось, как можно сделать по другому?

```
from random import randint as r

STAR = '*'
TOY = 'o'

height = int(input('\nEnter the number of height [2-20]: '))
width = 2 * height - 1


for i in range(1, width + 1, 2):
    tree = i * STAR
    tree_1 = tree.center(width, '_')
    if i == 7 or i == 9 or i == 19 or i == 21 or i == 31:
        i -= 1
    elif i == 11 or i == 23 or i == 33 or i == 35:
        i += 1
    if (i - 3) % 3 == 0:
        start = (width - i) // 2
        end = start + i
        my_list = list(tree_1)
        my_list[r(start, end)] = TOY
        tree_1 = ''.join(my_list)

print(tree_1)
```

Comment: [Как нарисовать ёлку используя только символы “_” и “*”?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/939754/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%91%d0%bb%d0%ba%d1%83-%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%b7%d1%83%d1%8f-%d1%82%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%ba%d0%be-%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8b-%d0%b8)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ваш код у меня вообще не отработал. Вот, Вам, мой пример генератора ёлки:

```
SPACE = '_'
STRAR = '*'

if __name__ == "__main__":
    rows = int(input())
    spaces = rows-1
    stars = 2

    for i in range(rows):
        print(
            (SPACE*spaces) +
            (STRAR*stars) +
            (SPACE*spaces)
        )
        stars += 2
        spaces -= 1
```

Вывод:

```
7
______**______
_____****_____
____******____
___********___
__**********__
_************_
**************
```

А вот с игрушками:

```
from random import randint


SPACE = '_'
STRAR = '*'


def toy(line):
    tmp = ''
    index = randint(0, len(line)-1)

    for i in range(len(line)):
        tmp += line[i] if i != index else 'o'

    return tmp


if __name__ == "__main__":
    rows = int(input())
    spaces = rows-1
    stars = 2

    for i in range(rows):
        print(
            (SPACE*spaces) +
            ((STRAR*stars) if (i % 2) != 0 else toy(STRAR*stars)) +
            (SPACE*spaces)
        )
        stars += 2
        spaces -= 1
```

Вывод:

```
7
______o*______
_____****_____
____***o**____
___********___
__*****o****__
_************_
************o*
```

Если нужен такой вывод:

```
10
_________o_________
________***________
_______***o*_______
______*******______
_____**o******_____
____***********____
___*****o*******___
__***************__
_**********o******_
*******************
```

То: `[21] stars = 1`

```
10
_________*_________
________o**________
_______*****_______
______*o*****______
_____*********_____
____o**********____
___*************___
__*************o*__
_*****************_
```

То: `[26] ((STRAR*stars) if (i % 2) == 0 else toy(STRAR*stars)) +`

Answer (score 1):

**Код:**

```
[print(' '*s + '*'*t) for s, t in zip(range(int(input('HEIGHT = '))-1, 0, -1), range(1, int(input('(again) HEIGHT = '))*2, 2))]
```

**Вывод:**

```
HEIGHT = 10
(again) HEIGHT = 10
         *
        ***
       *****
      *******
     *********
    ***********
   *************
  ***************
 *****************
```